# Trying to create HTML Canvas Tiles and make it Dynamic with the object movement

Tags: javascript, css, angular, canvas, html5-canvas

Trying to create a Canvas with tiles as it showed in the picture, Trying to move a vehicle object in all directions,is there solutions to achieve this functionality?

Functionality : Whenever the vehicle object move on the grid, the grid should rotate based on the vehicle movement, similar to google maps functionality.

Can anyone provide me the solution.

[image: image shown on front page]

Comment: Basically it's not possible to make your browser show your canvas which doesn't have width and height

Comment: Ok if i give fixed height and width, what if my object move out side of that height and width, that's where i got stuck with this, is there any solution for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An 'infinite' canvas is easy if you use an offset to draw all the objects by and perform some offscreen culling.

Toggle between views by clicking on the canvas.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  void function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   // lerp + 0.0 -> 1.0 smooth step
   function interpolate(value_1,value_2,t) {
    t = Math.max(0.0,Math.min(t,1.0));
    t = t * t * (3.0 - 2.0 * t);
    return value_1 + t * (value_2 - value_1);
   }
   
   function Camera(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = 0.0;
    this.zoom = 1.0;
    this.startX = 0.0;
    this.startY = 0.0;
    this.startAngle = 0.0;
    this.startZoom = 0.0;
    this.destX = 0.0;
    this.destY = 0.0;
    this.destAngle = 0.0;
    this.destZoom = 0.0;
    this.moveT = 0.0;
    this.target = null;
    this.targetOffsetX = 0.0;
    this.targetOffsetY = 0.0;
    this.state = this.STATE_IDLE;
   }
   
   Camera.prototype = {
    // States
    STATE_IDLE: 0,
    STATE_MOVING: 1,
    STATE_TRACKING: 2,
   
    // Const vars
    MOVE_T_INC: 0.01,
   
    set: function(x,y,angle,zoom) {
     this.destX = x;
     this.destY = y;
     this.destAngle = angle;
     this.destZoom = zoom;
     this.startX = this.x;
     this.startY = this.y;
     this.startAngle = this.angle;
     this.startZoom = this.zoom;
     this.moveT = 0.0;
     this.target = null;
     this.state = this.STATE_MOVING;
    },
    
    track: function(object,offsetX,offsetY,zoom) {
     if (object) {
      this.target = object;
      this.targetOffsetX = offsetX || 0.0;
      this.targetOffsetY = offsetY || 0.0;
      this.destX = object.x + this.targetOffsetX;
      this.destY = object.y + this.targetOffsetY;
      this.destAngle = object.angle;
      this.destZoom = zoom || this.zoom;
      this.startX = this.x;
      this.startY = this.y;
      this.startAngle = this.angle;
      this.startZoom = this.zoom;
      this.moveT = 0.0;
      this.state = this.STATE_MOVING;
     }
    },
    
    tick: function() {
     switch(this.state) {
      case this.STATE_MOVING: {
       if (this.target) {
        this.destX = this.target.x + this.targetOffsetX;
        this.destY = this.target.y + this.targetOffsetY;
        this.destAngle = this.target.angle;
       }
       
       this.x = interpolate(this.startX,this.destX,this.moveT);
       this.y = interpolate(this.startY,this.destY,this.moveT);
       this.angle = interpolate(this.startAngle,this.destAngle,this.moveT);
       this.zoom = interpolate(this.startZoom,this.destZoom,this.moveT);
       this.moveT += this.MOVE_T_INC;
       
       if (this.moveT >= 1.0) {
        this.state = this.target ? this.STATE_TRACKING : this.STATE_IDLE;
       }
      } break;
      
      case this.STATE_TRACKING: {
       if (this.target) {
        this.x = this.target.x + this.targetOffsetX;
        this.y = this.target.y + this.targetOffsetY;
        this.angle = this.target.angle;
       } else {
        this.state = this.STATE_IDLE;
       }
      }
     }
    }
   };
   
   function Point(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   }
   
   function Vehicle(x,y,path) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.path = path;
    this.currentPoint = 0;
    this.angle = 0.0;
    this.t = 0.0;
    this.startAngle = 0.0;
    this.targetAngle = 0.0;
    
    var point = this.path[this.currentPoint];
    var x = point.x - this.x;
    var y = point.y - this.y;
    var distance = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2.0) + Math.pow(y,2.0));
 
    this.t = 0.0;
    this.startAngle = this.angle;
    this.targetAngle = Math.atan2(y * distance,x * distance) + Math.PI * 0.5;
    this.state = this.STATE_TURNING;
   }
   
   Vehicle.prototype = {
    WIDTH: 20.0,
    HEIGHT: 40.0,
    TURN_SPEED: 0.01,
    MOVE_SPEED: 1.0,
    POINT_RADIUS: 1.0,
    
    STATE_MOVING: 0,
    STATE_TURNING: 1,
   
    tick: function() {
     var point = this.path[this.currentPoint];
     var x = point.x - this.x;
     var y = point.y - this.y;
     var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2.0) + Math.pow(y,2.0));
     
     switch(this.state) {
      case this.STATE_MOVING: {
       if (distance < this.POINT_RADIUS) {
        if (++this.currentPoint === this.path.length) {
         this.currentPoint = 0;
        }
        
        point = this.path[this.currentPoint];
        x = point.x - this.x;
        y = point.y - this.y;
        distance = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2.0) + Math.pow(y,2.0));
     
        this.t = 0.0;
        this.startAngle = this.angle;
        this.targetAngle = Math.atan2(y * distance,x * distance) + Math.PI * 0.5;
        this.state = this.STATE_TURNING;
       } else {
        distance = 1.0 / distance;
        this.x += x * distance * this.MOVE_SPEED;
        this.y += y * distance * this.MOVE_SPEED;
       }
      } break;
      
      case this.STATE_TURNING: {
       this.angle = interpolate(this.startAngle,this.targetAngle,this.t);
       this.t += this.TURN_SPEED;
       
       if (this.t >= 1.0) {
        this.state = this.STATE_MOVING;
       }
      } break;
     }
    },
    
    render: function(ctx,camera) {
     var x = (this.x - camera.x) * camera.zoom;
     var y = (this.y - camera.y) * camera.zoom;
     var angle = this.angle;
     var width = this.WIDTH * camera.zoom;
     var height = this.HEIGHT * camera.zoom;
    
     ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
     ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
     ctx.translate(x,y);
     ctx.rotate(angle);
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     ctx.rect(
      -width * 0.5,
      -height * 0.5,
      width,
      height
     );
     
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.rotate(-angle);
     ctx.translate(-x,-y);
    }
   };
   
   var tileWidth = 32;
   var tileHeight = 32;
   var invTileWidth = 1.0 / tileWidth;
   var invTileHeight = 1.0 / tileHeight;
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var camera = null;
   var vehicle = null;
   
   function loop() {
    // Tick
    vehicle.tick();
    camera.tick();
    
    // Render
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(-canvasWidth >> 1,-canvasHeight >> 1,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    // Draw Background
    var invZoom = 1.0 / camera.zoom;
    var maxX = (canvasWidth >> 1) * invZoom;
    var maxY = (canvasHeight >> 1) * invZoom;
    var minX = ((-maxX + camera.x) * invTileWidth) | 0;
    var minY = ((-maxY + camera.y) * invTileHeight) | 0;
    maxX = ((maxX + camera.x) * invTileWidth) | 0;
    maxY = ((maxY + camera.y) * invTileHeight) | 0;
    
    ctx.rotate(-camera.angle);
    ctx.lineWidth = camera.zoom;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    for (var x = minX - 2; x < maxX + 2; ++x) {
     for (var y = minY - 2; y < maxY + 2; ++y) {
      ctx.rect(
       (x * tileWidth - camera.x) * camera.zoom,
       (y * tileHeight - camera.y) * camera.zoom,
       tileWidth * camera.zoom,
       tileHeight * camera.zoom
      );
     }
    }
    
    ctx.stroke();
    
    vehicle.render(ctx,camera);
    ctx.rotate(camera.angle);
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   var toggle = false;
   
   onmousedown = function() {
    if (toggle = !toggle) {
     camera.track(vehicle,0.0,0.0,1.5);
    } else {
     camera.set(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }
   }
   
   onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.translate(canvasWidth >> 1,canvasHeight >> 1);
    
    var path = [];
    
    for (var i = 0, l = (Math.random() * 25) | 0; i < l; ++i) {
     path.push(new Point(
      Math.random() * canvasWidth - canvasWidth * 0.5,
      Math.random() * canvasHeight - canvasHeight * 0.5
     ));
    }
    
    camera = new Camera(0.0,0.0);
    vehicle = new Vehicle(0.0,0.0,path);
    
    loop();
   }
   
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```